# Streams, chars, and newlines

Tags: c++, newline, ostream

I have something similar to

```
const char* a = "a\nb";
std::ostream data;
```

and I need to read "a" into "data". I tried using

```
data_stream << data;
```

but that stops at the line end, so only "a" is copied. Next I tried

```
while (data[0] != '\0')
{
    data_stream << data;
}
```

however this does not remove the line from the char, so it's an endless loop. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You're sending `data` into `data_stream`. If you want to put `a` into `data` use `data << a`.

Comment: A newline wouldn't stop the stream from reading the whole string. It would read until the end of the string.

Comment: Are you trying to read until a newline into the output stream?

Comment: So was my answer below helpful? If so, could you accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `getline()` get every line int the char *

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you check that only "a" is copied? Can you present code and output for such check. The reason is, it should not happen: even if stream is flushed on "\n", it should still accept the following symbols ("b" in your example) after that.

Also your loop will indeed be infinite because you're checking for the first symbol every time, and it's naturally always not '\0' (since it's 'a'). What you probably intend to do is:

```
dp * char = data;  // creating pointer to char array
while (*dp)  // until the end of line is reached (at which point *dp evaluates to '/0' which is interpreted as false)
{
    data_stream << *dp++;  // outputting the char and moving pointer to the next one in array
}
```

And of course, as Captain Oblivious has pointed out, you need to get the names right in your second code piece.